# Mobile App : Appending div inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery

The main idea is I want to append div inside existing div but it doesn't seem to work. Here's the javascript code

```
function querySuccess(tx,results){
 var len = results.rows.length, i;
   for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
   $('#sap').append('<div class="swiper-slide"><img src="images/Real-Pattern/'+results.rows.item(i).originalPattern+'.jpg" height="180" width="100"/></div>');

}
};
```

and the here's the html

```
<div class="swiper-wrapper" id="sap">




        </div>
```

Can somebody explain to me what I did wrong there? Thanks in advance..

Comment: Are you sure that the `.append` line is actually running? That part of it looks fine to me.

Comment: What are you setting i to when you're getting the length of the rows? How about adding a console.log(results) as well in the sucess fn and debug it in firebug console to make sure you're accessing the object results correctly.

Comment: What is your 'tx' parameter? When you're passing in your 'results' parameter, does the function maybe think it's the 'tx' parameter, and thus doesn't use the 'results' object that you're wanting to append to #sap? If you don't use the 'tx' parameter, then remove it.

Comment: Also, can you show an example of what your 'results' object looks like?

Comment: tx is a websql database object. 

` function successCB() {
 

        db.transaction(queryDB,errorCB);
    }
 
 
 
 function queryDB(tx){
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM batikPattern',[],querySuccess,errorCB);
    }`

Comment: @Xymostech how to check if append actually running? I check the inspect element on chrome and shows no error about it

Comment: When I inspect the element finally the div show up but still it shows nothing on the page. Does it has to be kind of "refresh" to get the div inside the page? If so, how?